# Converting to ASCII with numbers above 128

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii

Simple question, yet should be simple answer ^_^ Looked around and found nothing. I'm using python 3.4 and can convert numbers up to 128 with the

```
print (chr(int))
```

method without trouble. 104 gives me "h", and 73 gives me "I".  However, when I use numbers higher than 128, it gives me the wrong thing. I think it's converting to unicode or something like that? I.e. 193 gives me Á instead of the "bottom" sign (upside down T).

Comment: Why do you know the answer is wrong above 128? What are you comparing to?

Comment: http://www.ascii-code.com/ are you using the correct encoding? what are you expecting?

Comment: According to the chart at http://www.ascii-code.com/, in the extended ASCII range 193 is "Á". Why are you expecting something different?

Comment: You need to show more code context - with python 3.4.2 on Windows, I get a `UnicodeEncodeError` with `print (chr(193))`. What exact code on what exact environment gives `Á`? See also @Martijn's answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All text in Python 3 is Unicode. ASCII just happens to be a *subset* of the Unicode standard.

So `chr(codepoint)` *always* converts to a Unicode character, where the first 128 codepoints also conform to the ASCII standard.

I'm not sure what you were expecting for values > 127 as the ASCII standard only contains 128 codepoints. Most codecs in use today are extensions of the ASCII standard; if you expected a specific codec, you need to use *bytes* and decode from that codec; to use the Windows 1252 codepage you could use:

```
>>> bytes([128]).decode('cp1252')
'€'
```

as that codepage defines codepoint 128 as the Euro sign, while the Unicode standard puts that (hex) [U+20AC](https://codepoints.net/U+20AC).

I think you were looking for [Codepage 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) here; a codepage that includes [box drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437); 193 indeed is an inverted T in that codepage:

```
>>> bytes([193]).decode('cp437')
'┴'
```

That's [U+2534 BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT UP AND HORIZONTAL](https://codepoints.net/U+2534) in the Unicode standard. To be absolutely clear: codepoints past 127 exist in codepage 437 but are **not ASCII**.

You may want to read up on Unicode and Python in this context:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: I would love to give another +1 for finding Cp437 - but you already got one from me.

Comment: @piet.t In general, I sometimes wished to be able to give "multi upvotes" for great answers ...

Comment: well i'm working with someone who's using python 2.7, and when he does chr(193) he gets the inverted T. I assumed something had gone wrong for me rather than him, from http://www.asciitable.com/, which shows 193 to be the inverted T.

Comment: @w1nter: In Python 2, you produce *bytes*. If their console or terminal is configured to use CP437 then printing `chr(193)` writes that byte to the terminal, and the *terminal* then interprets that byte as a character.

Comment: @w1nter: asciitable.com is *catastrophically* wrong. There is no such thing as *extended ASCII*, at least not as a standard. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII

Comment: @w1nter: you can do the same thing in Python 3, but you'd need to write bytes to `sys.stdout.raw`: `import sys; sys.stdout.raw.write(bytes([193]))` would produce the same character, provided the terminal or console is set to use that codepage. My Mac terminal is not; it uses UTF-8 instead.